# Как склоняется фамилия Тесла?

Tags: ономастика, склонение-фамилий

Вчера смотрел передачу, там рассказывали о Николе Тесла(е). И там его фамилию не склоняли по падежам. Но мне это резало слух — по-моему, фамилия все-таки должна склоняться. Тем более, что это славянская фамилия, то есть не совсем иноязычная.

Comment: Аналогично: смотрю старый добрый советский фильм про итальянцев в России и вижу: с участием (список) Луиджи БаллистА, но (как и надо) Евстигнеева, Аросевой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, фамилия нормативно склоняется.

Хотя она и не славянская в том понимании, какое вкладывается обычно при формулировке этого правила. Славянскими по происхождению считаются фамилии на -ски, -ин, -ев и т. п., т. е. те, которые можно сопоставить с аналогичными русскими, восходящими к притяжательным прилагательным, - и которые поэтому допускают склонение по типу прилагательных (адъективное).

Фамилия Тесла к таковым не относится. Хотя по происхождению она сербская, но не восходит к притяжательным формам и поэтому на неё не распространяются упомянутые рекомендации по парадигме склонения по типу прилагательных. Тем не менее, все фамилии, оканчивающиеся на неударное А, перед которой идет согласная, склоняются по типу существительных женского (оно же - первое школьное и второе академическое) склонения.
В том чиcле и Тесла: Тесла, Теслы, Тесле, Теслу, Теслой, (о) Тесле.

Традиция не склонять фамилию идет от ошибочного представления, что эта фамилия - французская и имеет ударение на последний слог. Для таких фамилий сделана оговорка о возможности несклонения, объясняемая более историческими причинами и традициями, чем логикой. Но, повторю, к фамилии Тесла это изъятие из общего правила неприменимо.

---

комментарии к комментариям.
~1. Вообще-то вопрос о происхождении не стоит. Но если уж говорить о нем, то сведение к плотницкому инструменту весьма спорно. Насколько понимаю, тесло - это даже не плотницкий инструмент, а скорее столярный - такой полутопор-полурубаночек, с набором функций вплоть для резьбы по дереву. И еще - для работы с камнем целый ряд инструментов...
Но как бы то ни было, много вы знаете людей с фамилией, скажем,  Рубанок или Уровень? Фамилии идут от прозвищ, прозвища - от профессий, личных качеств, свойств характера, встречаются "купеческие" фамилии от товара, коим торговали, семинарские фамилии... Но от инструмента?!
~2. Никак не могу согласиться с идей не склонять фамилию при каких бы то ни было условиях. С именем или без него - фамилия склоняется.

А, понял, насчет происхождения. "Тес" - согласен, корень, общий с тес, тесать. -л(о) - инструментальный суффикс, сраните: мыть - мыло, рыть - рыло, бить - било. Тесло - то, чем тешут. 
Сомнений в возможности прямого образования фамилии не снимает.
Из аналогов только Шило. Но это скорее всего - переносно, шилом могли прозвать длинного и худого человекаю Или по другой аналогии - колкого, острого на язык.

Comment: А как же быть, например, с украинскими фамилиями типа Карась, Перебийноса или, например, фамилия нашего директора - Иногда (с ударением на И)? Они не подходят под правило "-ски, -ин и т.д.", но их не славянскими никак не назовешь.

Comment: И что? Склоняются они, не вижу проблем. 
Да пускай они они будут славянскими по происхождению, но по форме это скорее прозвища, т.е. не те фамилии, на которые распространяется правило о склонении по типу прилагательных.  
Там речь идет о том, что славянские фамилии на -ски склоняются как русские на -ский, ну и некоторые другие, скажем славянские Чаплин или Дарвин имеют в творительном Чаплиным и Дарвиным, а их английские однофамильцы - Дарвином и Чаплином.     
Но это никак не значит, что славянские или неславянские фамилии другого типа не склоняются или имеют какой-то особый тип склонения.

Comment: >сведение к плотницкому инструменту весьма спорно. (...) много вы знаете людей с фамилией, скажем, Рубанок или Уровень? Фамилии идут от прозвищ, прозвища - от профессий, личных качеств, свойств характера

Согласен! Меня тут тоже "терзают смутные сомнения". Я вообще предполагал, что серб. "тесла" -- это как украинск. "тесля". А так на Украине называют плотника, и иногда столяра. http://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Тесля

Так свой ответ и начал, как можете видеть ниже :-). Потом посмотрел в укр. Википедии -- там выводят слово "тесля" от инструмента... Я перевёл и написал объяснение оттуда.

Comment: Дело в том, что современные словари сербского и хорватского дают перевод, что слова "плотник", что слова "столяр", словом "stolar". С другой стороны, в польском языке, к примеру, плотник - cieśla, a столяр - stolarz. Но есть ещё и "ложные друзья переводчика". http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ложные_друзья_переводчика. Например, "споро" по-хорватски это "медленно". Так что свои аналогии нужно проверять.

Но, соглашусь с Вами, логичнее было бы эту фамилию объяснить, как название профессии. Как Бондарь, Коваль и т.п.

Comment: >в польском языке... плотник - cieśla  

Точно? Т.е. Тесла -  может быть названием не только инструмента но и профессии хотя бы в польском?  Хорошо бы уточнить. 
Если так, то все возражения снимаю. Это уже аргумент, хотя язык в общем-то далекий от южнославянских, но такие вещи случайными не бывают.

ЗЫ Ссылка Ваше ведет на пустую страницу, но что такое ЛДП мне объяснять не надо.  
А, сообразил. Вот нормальная ссылка.  
http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%8C%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0

Comment: >Тесла - может быть названием не только инструмента но и профессии хотя бы в польском? Хорошо бы уточнить.

Вот, к примеру, статья польской Википедии

http://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cieśla

а вот соответствующая на русском

http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Плотник

В конце обеих статей под заголовком **Известные плотники** : Пётр I Великий, Харрисон Форд. На польском яз. заголовок выглядит как "Przykłady osób historycznych pracujących jako cieśle", т.е. "Примеры исторических личностей, работавших плотниками". Следовательно статья "Плотник"  о том же, что и статья "Cieśla".

Comment: http://mrtranslate.ru/translate/russian-polish.html
По этой ссылке переводчик ImTranslator переводит "плотник" как "cieśla", а переводчик Google, как "stolarz".

Comment: Название  инструмента  тоже  может  быть  прозвищем.

Answer (score 2):

В укр. языке *тесля* или *тесляр* -- это плотник. И вообще, "тес-" -- это старинный славянский корень. Фамилию Тесла можно склонять в русском языке.

Раньше *тесляр* обобщённо называли мастера по обработке древесины у славян.

Название "тесляр" возникло от одного из 2-х самых распространённых инструментов мастера -- тесла (второй -- топор). Разнца между ними в том, что с помощью тесла обрабатывали древесину вдоль и под углом к волокнам, а топором можно было рубить и поперёк.

В слав. языках осталось название инструмента: укр. тесло, бел. цясло, русс. тесло, болгар. тесла, серб., словац. и чеш. - tesla. Похоже на латышском -- teslis.

Со временем для более сложных работ по дереву стали использовать слово *столяр*.

[Источник, на укр.языке](http://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Тесляр)

Фамилия Тесля (похожая на фамилию Тесла) встречается на Украине.
[Пример](http://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Тесля_Григорій_Терентійович)